# Renaming multiple layers in the legend from an attribute in each layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, affine-transformation, rename

I have 72 layers that have been generated via affine transform of a single layer that has 72 categories. But the 72 layers have been given names that are sequential numeric. The original categories are named by a field `UNIT_NAME`. I want the 72 generated layers to have this attribute as a layer name for each of them.

Can I get affine transform function to name the generated layers using the value from the `UNIT_NAME` attribute of each layer; or can I rename all the layers to have this value, in a script?

I am using QGIS 3.16.1 Hannover on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you sure you used `affine transformation`?

Comment: How the layers panel and `UNIT_NAME` attribute look like? For features in one layer, they have the same `UNIT_NAME` value?

Comment: Erik. I am sure.

Comment: Kadir - The UNIT_NAME is different for every category - there are 72 different categories with unique UNIT_NAMEs

Comment: @Erik - I have to apologise to you - I was convinced it was `affine transform`, but it wasn't - it was `split vector layer` I used. Thanks for spotting my error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a script like this:

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

for layer in layers:
    # get the first feature's UNIT_NAME value
    name = layer.getFeature(0)["UNIT_NAME"]
    layer.setName(name)
```

Note: The script changes the name of the single layer that has 72 categories, too, if it exists in Layers panel. So you can add an `if` statement to pass that layer.

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

for layer in layers:
    if layer.name() == "NAME_OF_THE_SINGLE_LAYER":
        continue

    name = layer.getFeature(0)["UNIT_NAME"]
    layer.setName(name)
```

Comment: And be sure all layers have `UNIT_NAME` field. Otherwise you get an error.

Comment: Thanks Kadir, that worked perfectly. I shall keep that script for future reference. I shall try modifying the if statement in the second script to pick out all layers with name starting "xxxx"

Answer (score 4):

So extending Kadir's answer, because I did not want all layers to be renamed, just those that got assigned names with a specific string through affine transform, I came up with the following, which worked nicely.

```py
import re
RES_STRING='Palinspastic'
STRING=re.compile(RES_STRING)
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    LAYER_NAME=layer.name()
    if STRING.search(LAYER_NAME):
        name = layer.getFeature(0)["UNIT_NAME"]
        layer.setName(name)
```